# Find an explicit homotopy equivalence for the three figures

Tags: algebraic-topology

On Allen Hatcher's book we have three figures, and the graphs shown in bold lines are homotopy equivalent to each other since they are deformation retracts of the same space. But I want to know how to find a direct homotopy equivalent from one graph to another?

For example, we can construct an obvious map $f$ from the first graph to the second by mapping two circles to the two deformed circles, and the horizontal line in between to the connecting point of the two deformed circles. But how to get another $g$ backwards so that $fg\simeq1_{\mathrm{Graph}\ 2}$ and $gf\simeq1_{\mathrm{Graph}\ 1}$?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that they are all deformation retracts of the same space tells you how to find homotopy equivalences between them: compose the inclusion of one graph into the large space with the deformation retraction of the large space onto the other graph.

Doing this for the first and the second graph gives the map you describe. A homotopy inverse from the second to the first graph can obtained as follows: we can view the second graph as union of two closed arcs and an $X$-like shape, only intersecting at the endpoints of the arcs. Identifying pairs of points lying above one another on the $X$-like shape, we obtain a line segment. Dragging the open arcs along the endpoints while "pinching" this $X$-like shape to a line segment, they turn into circles (since the endpoints get identified) and these are the two circles connected by that line segment, which constitute the first graph. Now if you look closely at the pictures, you can rightfully complain that this description is not the exact same thing as what you get when you follow the outline in my first paragraph (the difference being that, following Hatcher's pictures, we also have to do a bit of stretching outward from the middle when pincing the $X$-like shape to a line segment, but that's the same thing up to homotopy), but I find this version cleaner.